# Boost Libraries: Unable to link regex library on MAC OS X

Tags: regex, macos, boost, linker

I'm trying to use the Boost Libraries ... but to no avail. I attempted to follow the **Getting Started** tutorial on Boost's website (for Unix Variants), but having problems along the way.

I compiled the libraries into a directory in my Downloads folder:

```
/Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled
```

When I use the full path to the library ... The example program (given on the Boost Website) compiles and links fine.

```
g++ -o boostTesting boostTesting.cpp -I /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/include/ /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib/libboost_regex.a
```

However, when I attempt to link the using the -L and -l options ... it fails ...

```
g++ -o boostTesting boostTesting.cpp -I /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/include/ -L /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib/ -l boost_regex

ld: library not found for -lboost_regex
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

g++ -o boostTesting boostTesting.cpp -I /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/include/ -L /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib/ -l libboost_regex

ld: library not found for -llibboost_regex
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

g++ -o boostTesting boostTesting.cpp -I /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/include/ -L /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib/ -l regex

ld: library not found for -lregex
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My shell is bash ... and I've set my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to the following:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:/Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib
```

It appears I'm not using the correct name to link (with the -l) option. Can somebody please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There shouldn't be a space between `-L` and `/Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib/`
- Make sure that `libboost_regex.a` is compiled in `/Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib`.

Then this should work:

```
g++ -o boostTesting boostTesting.cpp -I/Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/include/ -L/Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib/ -lboost_regex
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! That solved it. For some reason, the space between -L and the /Users/myUsername/Downloads/boostCompiled/lib/ was causing the issue. Additionally, I removed the space betweek -l and boost_regex. It works!